# lookup auto_refresh property of external table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How can you look up the `auto_refresh` property of an external table, either using SQL or Snowsight? I have tried `DESCRIBE EXTERNAL TABLE [myname] TYPE = STAGE` but there is no column in the output for the `auto_refresh` property. It also doesn't show anything in the Snowsight UI.

Comment: `SELECT GET_DDL('TABLE', 'myname')`